# PROMQL replace values

Tags: prometheus, promql

Has anyone ever done any logic like this, or would have any idea how I can solve this.

I use `WriteLatency{DBInstanceIdentifier=~"aurora-mysql.*"} > 0` to filter who is the **master** of my database.

The result of **Query 1** will be: `WriteLatency{DBInstanceIdentifier="aurora-mysql-2"}` where **aurora-mysql-2** is the **master** database.

To validate the uptime, I use the following query `mysql_global_status_uptime{instance=" <HERE>"}`.

I need the result of the **DBInstanceIdentifier** label in **Query 1** to be inserted as a value in **Query 2** in the **instance** field. That way, I can have a query in which I check the uptime of the master database only.